# AngularJS won't let me load another page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to have a link that goes to another page and nothing I do has any visible effect on the page. I have tried:

- `<a href="url">`
- `<a href="url" target="_self">`
- `<a ng-click="register()">`

where register is a controller function, with the function bodies I've tried:

- `$window.location.href(url)`
- `$window.location.href = url`
- `$window.location = url`

all followed by `$window.location.reload()` (which does not even refresh the page after failing to change the URL). Every single method was accepted as a valid answer for other people asking the same question. I am using angular 1.2 which is fairly old.

EDIT: Sorry for not beign more specific to avoid confusion; url is just a placeholder for an inline string and all my elements are closed properly. I was just trying to quickly list all methods I've seen from other pages on this site (which all failed). I am also in html5mode for $location.

Comment: Angular is designed for single page apps -- why are you trying to change the page?

Comment: To let the user leave the app to some certain destination probably. It's not unheard of ;)

Comment: @TomekSułkowski yes that would make sense, just wanted to make sure he wasn't expecting another page of his app to interoperate with the initial page

Comment: Is `url` a variable on the scope? If so, you should write it in brackets: `<a href="{{ url }}" target="_self">`

Comment: I was just using url as a placeholder, I have a string guarded with ' in the actual HTML

Comment: I'm confused; Angular doesn't control if a browser can navigate through an `<a>` tag; are you trying to say that you want angular to respond to the link click and it's not? are you getting any errors in the console?  Or are you saying that you want angular to generate a link for you from a variable value?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I usually do it. In your html:

```
<a href="javascript:" ng-click="register();">Register here!</a>
```

And in your controller, you would have a function like this:

```
$scope.register = function() {
    $window.location = '#/register';
};
```

For example, you homepage is `domain.com/#/home` and you try to link to `domain.com/#/register`.

Comment: I can change the URL with this method but the page doesn't reload, and neither `$window.location.reload()` nor `window.location.reload()` do anything when called within angular (the latter works if called from the console).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$location.path("/Home/Index....");
```

$location must be injected into the controller.
Use this on your ng-click event. [$location.path](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Don't know if you've done it but your HTML should look like:

```
<a ng-href="{{url}}">
```

Comment: Using ng-href successfully changes the URL, but does not reload the page. Angular seems to be blocking my calls to `$window.location.reload()` and `window.location.reload` since neither one does anything in a service or directive, but the latter works in the console.

Comment: Maybe you can clearify the "reload the page", what shall happen if you force this reload?
Angular uses HTML-5 technology to set the url and loads internal the new url and content.

If you want to force the page-reload try
```$location.path('/Home/Index...'); $route.reload();``` [$route.reload](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a html typo, but did you write them in a good syntax ?

```
<a href="url">My link </a>

<a href="url" target="_self">My link </a>

<a ng-click="register()">My link </a>
```

Comment: Yes, that should work. For the `ng-click` link I would add `href="#"` to have normal link styles. Please have a look at this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7X89bJSrZg8eq372WN0O?p=preview).

Comment: you shouldn't  put an `ng-click` on `<a>` tag, use a `span`, `div` or `p` instead

Comment: Adding a leading # to the url made this method successfully change the URL, which it didn't previously, but it still does not reload the page due to html5mode.